# A is more near to B than C (is or does)?

Tags: grammaticality

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> The approximate data values are much closer to the real data values than the original ones **are**.
>   The approximate data values are much closer to the real data values than the original ones **do**.

Thanks!

Comment: If the sentence made sense, *are* would be the word to use, not *do*.  But it seems to me that most readers will equate “real data values” and “original ones”, ie will take those two phrases as referring to the same values, in which case the sentence makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want *are*, because that’s the trait (*be closer*) that you’re comparing with “more than”:

> X *are* more Y than Z *are*.

You would use *do* if you were comparing actions:

> I exercise more often than my friend does.